# What's Ethereum's mechanism for transitioning to new consensus rules?

Tags: consensus

In Bitcoin, historically, several ways to fork the network in have been used:

- User Activated Soft Fork (UASF): on a certain hardcoded blockchain height the nodes simply start enforcing the new rules
- Miner Activated Soft Fork (MASF): the new rule activation happens if a majority of miners signal readiness (and does not happen in case of a timeout)
- The process specified by BIP 8 (combination of the previous two)

What is the corresponding process in Ethereum and is there an EIP that specifies it?